# User permission in MVC design pattern

Tags: model-view-controller, design-patterns, permissions

Large systems is using by many users, therefore they can log into the system and then they have extra permissions. Permissions are different, such as permission to view detailed information about other users or permissions to perform different actions. Good practice in software development is using design patterns. One of them is MVC (Model-View-Controller). So, my question is: in which layer of the model should have been checking the permissions ? Is that application logic should validate user permissions or perhaps in view layer some options should be hidden/locked/etc ?

Comment: See this question in Software Engineering SE: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/220574/where-should-user-permission-checks-take-place-in-and-mvc-and-by-who

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The authentication and authorization is not part of MVC design pattern itself. Nor it is directly a responsibility of any of the basic MVC building blocks.

A solution that you can explore would be to place the access control in a decorator.

You create a `Container` instance, in which you can inject an object (it might be either some controller, view or maybe a service from model layer) and some authorization manager-thing. Then you call a method on this container as if it was the original object. If call gets cleared with access manager, then you execute the method. Otherwise you raise an exception.

> <sub>Unfortunately code example is in PHP, because that's my "native" language</sub>

```
$something = new SomeThing;
$data = $something->getSensitiveData(); // will simply return all the information

$accessCheck = new AccessManager( .. some dependencies .. );
$something = new Container( $something, $accessCheck );
try 
{
    $data = $something->getSesitiveData(); 
    // will return all information if you pass the authorization.
} 
catch ( AccessDeniedException $e )
{
    // do something
}
```

This approach has several benefits:

1. The access management is centralized
2. You can inject any instance in such container
3. Will not cause OCP violation
4. Let's you defer the addition of authorization while developing

The "wrapping" in such decorator would happen usually at within the factory which creates your instance.

As to which part of MVC triad you should be wrapping. Well ... usually it is enough to wrap the controller (especially when working with MVC in context of Web). But, depending on how you structure the rest of you codebase, it might be reasonable to add this kind of authorization checks also for services (group of classes/instances in model layer).

The  thing is, this approach has no restrictions on granularity. You can add this type of access control on any object. Even if you have not access to the source code of that object.